# ¿Como puedo hacer la función "boton atras" history.pushState en la misma pagina?

Tags: javascript

Mi problema es que no puedo registrar en el historial porque no salto a otra pagina o no estoy usando enlaces de anclaje para recorrer la pagina.
Toda la pagina la manejo con document.querySelectorAll desplazándome con:

```js
function reset(){
  for(let i=0; i< pege.length; i++){
    page[i].style.display ='none';
  }
}

function pagina1(){
  reset();
  page[2].style.display = 'block';
}

function pagina1(){
  reset();
  page[3].style.display = 'block';
}
```

etc... Como no salto a otra pagina, no cambio el historial, y como tampoco son enlaces de ancla, tampoco los puedo registrar en el historial.

Comment: No acabo de ver la relación entre el código expuesto y el título de la pregunta. ¿Qué hace `reset()`?

Comment: Lo que hace es: function reset(){ for(let i=0; i< pege.length; i++{page[i].style.display ='none'; pero no se como poder dirigir el history o el "boton atras" a un page[2].style.display = block;

Comment: Creo que necesitaremos más detalles: puedes pulsar en [edit] y mejorar la pregunta con más datos, en lugar de ponerlos en los comentarios. Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y entender qué es un [mcve]

Comment: ¿De esta forma se comprende mas? El problema es que no puedo registrar en el historial porque no salto a otra pagina o no estoy usando enlaces de anclaje para recorrer la pagina.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es usar el API History: https://www.arkaitzgarro.com/html5/capitulo-16.html

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puedes añadir un ID a cada elemento que ocultas o muestras y añadir eso como ancla:

```
function gotoPage(num) {
  reset();
  page[num].style.display ='block';
  const ID = page[num].id;
  history.pushState({page: num}, `Página ${num}`, `index.html#${ID}`);
}
```

Comment: ¡Hola Pablo! Aunque ya lo intenté como me recomiendas, no he podido solucionarlo. Seguiré buscando una solución. Mil gracias por la ayuda.